# I can't block port 22 to a specific IP (windows server 2008R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, windows-firewall

I'm using Bitvise SSH server and recently get a connection attempt every minute from one IP number. Bitvise terminates the connection immediately, but it's been going on every minute for days and I just want to block that IP number.

I've tried adding a rule in the firewall but it seems to just ignore the rule. I don't know what I'm doing wrong -- I added a new rule, set it to block traffic, added the IP number, applied and saved the rule.

Bitvise does add its own rule to the firewall to allow traffic through port 22 to itself, and I thought maybe there was a conflict, but there's no way to prioritize/order rules in Windows firewall. I tried making my rule more specific by specifying port 22, but that didn't seem to help.

Thanks

Comment: Well, check again and make sure you have created the rule correctly and firewall is itself active and the rule is created in inbound rules. You dont need to specify port or protocol, just to block an ip, can configure for any port/protocol/program. Can compare here: http://www.studyblog.net/2011/10/block-ip-address-or-ip-range-in-windows-server-2008-by-windows-firewall/

Comment: Do you have a firewall (appliance or router) in front of your server (you really should if you don't)? You could block it there, and the traffic will never reach your server.

Comment: At this host, I don't have control of the appliance in front of the server. It takes them days to respond. And, I'm sure I'll have to do this again sometime.

Comment: I am having this very same problem. Bitvise appears to have some "tricks" on its app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom rule in windows firewall to do this (unless you're trying to use some other firewall) go to windows firewall click inbound rules, click new rule, click custom rule, click protocol and ports, Protocol type would be tcp, choose specific port and enter 22, enter the IP you're trying to block under scope, under action choose Block the connection, and that should do it

Comment: This is what I've tried doing. It seems all in order to me but it just doesn't seem to block the incoming traffic. I didn't specify any ports, though -- just the IP.

Comment: I did read that if rules conflict (like mine do -- the SSH server allows all traffic to itself via port 22, but my rule blocks the specific IP), the more specific rule wins. So I figured just blocking an IP isn't that specific, so I added port 22 as well. Still didn't work.

Comment: Thats strange, i guess the next thing i'd try is restarting the windows firewall service

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the "Access Control" rules, but after a while the Bitvise app can obey you:

https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?WinSSHD.1.17727.2

> in order to block all IPs except a list of IPs you allow, use the
> feature Access Control > Hosts: IP rules in Advanced WinSSHD Settings.
>
> The default IP rule is:
>
> IP address: 0.0.0.0 Significant bits: 0 Allow connect: checked
>
> To permit login for only a list of IPs, change this into a series of
> rules, as follows:
>
> 10.1.2.3 / 32 / allowed
>
> 10.1.2.4 / 32 / allowed
>
> 0.0.0.0 / 0 / not allowed
>
> The above three rules will allow connections from 10.1.2.3 and
> 10.1.2.4, but no others

That last rule is important, the default for bitvise is to permit connections.